# Getting JTextField user input returns initial null value

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield

When typing new text into the JTextFields, getText keeps returning the initial null value of the JTextFields when pressing the create button. What methods should be added to update the JTextField values to the new user input?

```
public class NewQuizWindow {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField[] textfields = new JTextField[4];
    private String[] inputs = new String[textfields.length];
    private JButton create;

    public NewQuizWindow() {

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        initialise();
    }

    public JPanel initialise(){

        //print initial labels, buttons
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Please fill in the required fields below.");        
        Dimension size = l1.getPreferredSize();
        l1.setBounds(225 - size.width/2, 50, size.width, size.height );
        panel.add(l1);

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Title");     
        size = title.getPreferredSize();
        title.setBounds(10, 100, size.width, size.height);
        panel.add(title);

        JLabel description = new JLabel("Description");
        size = description.getPreferredSize();
        description.setBounds(10, 130, size.width, size.height);
        panel.add(description);

        JLabel location = new JLabel("Location");
        size = location.getPreferredSize();
        location.setBounds(10, 160, size.width, size.height);
        panel.add(location);

        JLabel date_time = new JLabel("Date");
        size = date_time.getPreferredSize();
        date_time.setBounds(10, 190, size.width, size.height);
        panel.add(date_time);

        JLabel l = new JLabel("(yyyy-mm-dd)");
        l.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        size = l.getPreferredSize();
        l.setBounds(10, 200, size.width, size.height);
        panel.add(l);

        create = new JButton("Create");
        size = create.getPreferredSize();
        create.setBounds(225- size.width/2, 230, size.width, size.height);
        panel.add(create);

        //initialise textfields
        for(int i = 0; i< textfields.length; i++){
            textfields[i] = new JTextField();
            textfields[i].setBounds(100, 95+30*i, 300, 25);
            textfields[i].setEditable(true);
            panel.add(textfields[i]);
        }

        //create actionlistener, reading textfields
        create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                for(int i = 0; i< textfields.length; i++){

                    inputs[i] = textfields[i].getText();
                    System.out.println("-" +textfields[i].getText()+ "-");

                }


            }
        });

        return panel;

    }


}
```

Comment: Your code does not show the problem. It has other problems though, including use of `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)`.

Comment: What is bad about using null layouts? And what influence does it have on the getText() method?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your problem, but as mentioned, your code above does not **show** your problem. It is though a sign of a newbie's Swing program since if you do these for long enough, you'll know that programs that use null layouts are extremely difficult to maintain and upgrade. You're far better off learning about and using the layout managers as they will give your programs much greater flexibility and power, and make it much easier to change them later. But regarding your original problem, you will need to debug first to find out where it's coming from.